# How does D3JS send data into events

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

I have an unclear understanding to sending data in D3JS, and I hope that someone could explain to me about that. Firstly, I am going to show my code, and then I will represent to you my issue.

```
d3.dsv(';','files/d3.csv').then(function(data){
var s_w = 600;
var s_h = 500;
var svg2 = d3.select('.font_tem_export_content_3')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width',s_w)
        .attr('height',s_h);
    ///bars
    var gg2 = svg2.append('g')
                .attr('transform','translate(60,'+30+')')
        gg2.selectAll('.d3_bars')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('x',function(d){
              return x_scale3(d.year);
            })
            .attr('y',function(d){
              return y_scale3(d.value);
            })
            .attr('width', x_scale3.bandwidth())
            .on('mouseover',onMouseOver);
});
    function onMouseOver(d,i){
        console.log(d);
    }
```

Then I got results when I had moved my mouse into those elements 'rect':

> {stt: "9", name: "I", age: "18", gender: "nữ", year: "2018", …}

Personally, I do not know why the function `onMouseOver` is outside `d3.dsv(';','files/d3.csv').then(function(data){}`, they still can get value of them (var `d` in function).
Besides, how were they be stored in client screen? (I have not seen any data in html code).
Would someone mind help me.

Answer (score 1):

- d3.selection.on(type[, listener[, capture]]) adds an event listener
  to each element in the current selection
- D3 invokes the listener in the same way it invokes other D3 operator
  functions - by passing the current datum "d", index "i", and the
  "this" context as the current DOM element
- Notice D3 allows you to take advantage of capture phase versus
  bubbling phase event triggers
- d3.event captures an event when it happens and stores it in the
  variable d3.event
- The d3.event variable is a global variable that can be used in the
  event listener callback function registrered with the d3.selection.on
  operator
- After the JavaScript callback function has finished running, the
  current d3.event variable is reset
- You can "delete" an event listener by passing the JavaScript null
  object as the function for the eventListener type

Comment: Thanks so much @QASIM KHAN. After I had read your explaination, I got some knowledges about my issue, But i have been confused, I will talk my opinion and would you mind suggest to me a comment?
I selected all `.d3_bars`, then i send data. So this means any `eventlistener` call from an element belong with `d3_bars` can use it. One element will catch with a `value d` and an `index i `.
When i put an `event` in an `element`, and  this event call a function have two parameters are `d, i`. it will understand automaticly they are `value d` and `index i `. and will be stored in "event variable"